# Calling main() of another python script and getting STDOUT result

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to call another local script using subprocess.

The local script prints it's result to the screen.

**Local:**

```
def main():
    """
        main function
        controls the method call, the method is decided by TS runner
    """

    sParams = ScriptParamHandler()
    paramsList = ['TestName']  # ordered list of parameters
    paramsDict = sParams.AnalyzeParametersForScript(paramsList)

    mainReturn = None

    with ProductXXXXX() as testSequence:

        testSequence.testFixture.InitDevices()

        func = getattr(testSequence, paramsDict['TestName'])

        returnVal = func()

        print paramsDict['TestName'], "\n", returnVal, "\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Caller Script:**

```
with BasicRunner(testSet, testSetLocation, paramsDict['ProfileName']) as testRunner:

    if testRunner.CheckFolderAndFile():

        testRunner.GetProfile()

        for test in testRunner.testList:

            testRunner.logger.Info("Test {} started...".format(test))

            testResult = subprocess.call(testRunner.tsPyFile + " " + test, shell=True)

            testRunner.logger.Info("Test {} result {}".format(test, testResult))

    else:

        pass
```

I want caller script `testResult` to be the `stout` of the local script.

I've tried `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `subprocess.check_output()` but with no luck, maybe some one can give me some a better direction?

Comment: did you try testResult.communicate() instead of subprocess.check_output()? (with stdout=subprocess.PIPE ofcourse)

Comment: you could also redirect stdout when the script is run within the same python process. Though it is [more complex if the child script produces non-Python output such as output from external subprocesses, C extension libraries, etc](https://gist.github.com/zed/991e006c822740aa6896#file-parent-py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by @shshank comment, this is the solution:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', testRunner.tsPyFile, test], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdoutValue = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: As I've mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20278271/4279), `.communicate()` is a better than `check_output()` if it is known that the child script may fail. You should probably accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [plumbum](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEwQFjAE&url=https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumbum&ei=lDaXUp6oCIe27QaB8oGQCw&usg=AFQjCNEIJAuwBazKFT8I0szsTZnClGs92g&bvm=bv.57155469,d.ZGU).  It would make your life so much easier.

```
from plumbum.cmd import python
stdout = python[testRunner.tsPyFile][test]()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.communicate()` is the way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20266442/4279) to get merged stdout/stderr from another Python script that might fail. But here's `check_output()` variant, just to show how it can be done:

```
import sys
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT, CalledProcessError

try:
    stdout_value = check_output(
        [sys.executable or 'python', testRunner.tsPyFile, test], stderr=STDOUT)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    stdout_value = e.output
```